# How do I disable voiceover when I cannot log into my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, voiceover

My toddler started pressing buttons like a madman and now I am in voiceover and locked out of my iPhone 8, because even though I hit on passcode numbers and voiceover kindly tells me what my passcode is, it does not log me into my iPhone and I can't use Siri either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this ever happens to you, you have to hit the Home button on an iPhone 8 about three times and voiceover is disabled.